# Heroku PX dynos application crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn, amazon-rds

Why when we are use PX dynos Heroku application crashed?

We are use Unicorn and Amazon RDS.
What numbers connection pool need to PX dynos?

It is work for 1X and 2X dynos but not work PX dynos.